# Asp.net Treeview set checkbox id

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I inherited code that uses the asp.net `TreeView`. There is a bug. I need to set the checkbox in the `treeview` from the server side. So, when the form is posted back later I can grab the values. This is what I have, I cannot find any means to set the checkbox. Any help would be appreciated

```
TreeNode ndGroup = new TreeNode(o.GroupName);
ndGroup.Value = o.GroupID.ToString();
ndGroup.ImageUrl = str_AdGroupImg; 
ndGroup.ShowCheckBox = true;
TreeNode ndsubMember;
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(submem.Department))
{
    ndsubMember = new TreeNode(submem.MemberName);
}
else
{
    ndsubMember = new TreeNode(submem.MemberName + " (Dept - " + submem.Department + ")");
}
//TreeNode ndsubMember = new TreeNode(submem.MemberName);
ndsubMember.Value = submem.MemberID.ToString();
ndsubMember.ImageUrl = str_AdMeneberImg;  
ndsubGroup.ChildNodes.Add(ndsubMember);
ndGroup.ChildNodes.Add(ndsubGroup);
trvEmailGroups.Nodes.Add(ndGroup);
trvEmailGroups.CollapseAll();
```

Comment: Please add some more context to the question, especially that the controls are created dynamically is important. Some more code would also be helpful. Maybe you can use a Repeater to avoid the dynamically created controls.

Comment: ok the asp.net page has 3 divs, the treeview is on the first div, the other 2 are hidden. Each div has control dynamically created from a class, different properties of said class are bound to different dynamic controls all using the id of the class in the id's, example txt_1234, rdo_1234, chk_1234, now this was done so all the data from each control could be collected when the form is posted. so I need a was to set /get the id of the checkboxes that are created by the treeview